# Is there a direct way to determine Git's @{-N} branch, without e.g. parsing a log or silently running checkout?

Tags: git

I'd like a way in Git to determine the branch `@{-N}` refers to, something I could use in scripts.

It does not appear to be surfaced anywhere. I can think of a few ways to build the functionality myself, for example parsing `.git/logs/HEAD`, writing to a custom log file at `post-checkout` (both workable solutions but they feel heavy handed), or silently running `checkout @{-N}` and then silently running `checkout -` (slow, doesn't necessarily play nice with a dirty working tree, and changes the checkout stack).

But is there a way I can get it directly? For example is there a way to use the functions Git itself is using, without copying over a significant chunk of Git's source? I believe the syntax was first introduced in https://github.com/git/git/commit/8415d5c7ef63237f6efab0c9aef0b0fdbcbfda25 (`git branch`) and https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9717ee97075bb333684fa2f63e9136c5f7d89bf (`git merge`), where it's calculated with internal functions I'm not familiar with.

I'd also be interested in comments pointing to other commits in Git source related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}
refs/tags/v2.1.0
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-2}
refs/heads/master
```

Be aware that if there's no symbolic full name for one of these, this particular form outputs *nothing:*

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-3}
$ git rev-parse @{-3}
6c4ab27f2378ce67940b4496365043119d7ffff2
```

This happens because `@{-3}` wasn't a branch at all, it was a raw commit hash.

Comment: Makes sense  So `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-N} 2>/dev/null` and default to `git rev-parse @{-N} 2>/dev/null` and if -N is too far back the output is "@{-N}". So simple, thanks!

Comment: It's also up to you to decide whether to skip things like the tag (@{-1} above was a tag). I assume `git checkout -` does that, moving on to @{-2} which in this case would succeed.

Comment: `git checkout @{-N}` (and `git checkout -`) stacks checked out branches and commits. If you check out tag "my-tag" and then check out a branch, `git checkout -` will put you back on the commit tagged "my-tag". I was a little loose in my question write up